# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: states.filter is not a function at searchStates

Tags: javascript, json

```js
[
    {
        "abbr": "AL",
        "name": "Alabama",
        "web": "www.google.com",
        "capital": "Montgomery",
        "lat": "32.361538",
        "long": "-86.279118"
    },
    {
        "abbr": "AK",
        "name": "Alaska",
        "capital": "Juneau",
        "lat": "58.301935",
        "long": "-134.419740"
    },
    {
        "abbr": "AZ",
        "name": "Arizona",
        "capital": "Phoenix",
        "lat": "33.448457",
        "long": "-112.073844"
    },
    {
        "abbr": "AR",
        "name": "Arkansas",
        "capital": "Little Rock",
        "lat": "34.736009",
        "long": "-92.331122"
    },
    {
        "abbr": "CA",
        "name": "California",
        "capital": "Sacramento",
        "lat": "38.555605",
        "long": "-121.468926"
    },
    {
        "abbr": "CO",
        "name": "Colorado",
        "capital": "Denver",
        "lat": "39.7391667",
        "long": "-104.984167"
    },
    {
        "abbr": "CT",
        "name": "Connecticut",
        "capital": "Hartford",
        "lat": "41.767",
        "long": "-72.677"
    },
    {
        "abbr": "DE",
        "name": "Delaware",
        "capital": "Dover",
        "lat": "39.161921",
        "long": "-75.526755"
    },
    {
        "abbr": "FL",
        "name": "Florida",
        "capital": "Tallahassee",
        "lat": "30.4518",
        "long": "-84.27277"
    },
    {
        "abbr": "GA",
        "name": "Georgia",
        "capital": "Atlanta",
        "lat": "33.76",
        "long": "-84.39"
    },
    {
        "abbr": "HI",
        "name": "Hawaii",
        "capital": "Honolulu",
        "lat": "21.30895",
        "long": "-157.826182"
    },
    {
        "abbr": "ID",
        "name": "Idaho",
        "capital": "Boise",
        "lat": "43.613739",
        "long": "-116.237651"
    },
    {
        "abbr": "IL",
        "name": "Illinois",
        "capital": "Springfield",
        "lat": "39.783250",
        "long": "-89.650373"
    },
    {
        "abbr": "IN",
        "name": "Indiana",
        "capital": "Indianapolis",
        "lat": "39.790942",
        "long": "-86.147685"
    },
    {
        "abbr": "IA",
        "name": "Iowa",
        "capital": "Des Moines",
        "lat": "41.590939",
        "long": "-93.620866"
    },
    {
        "abbr": "KS",
        "name": "Kansas",
        "capital": "Topeka",
        "lat": "39.04",
        "long": "-95.69"
    },
    {
        "abbr": "KY",
        "name": "Kentucky",
        "capital": "Frankfort",
        "lat": "38.197274",
        "long": "-84.86311"
    },
    {
        "abbr": "LA",
        "name": "Louisiana",
        "capital": "Baton Rouge",
        "lat": "30.45809",
        "long": "-91.140229"
    }
]
```

I have the following code, when I get my data (i exported the .json file in my local repository above) from local storage as you can see in the commented section of the code below, it works correctly. When I am trying to get my data from an external url gives me "TypeError: states.filter is not a function at searchStates" error. How can I get my data from an external url? (From the external url,I can read the .json file and I can see its content with "console.log" but I am getting this error while trying to filter it)

```js
const search = document.getElementById('search');
const matchList = document.getElementById('match-list');

const searchStates = async searchText =>{
    

    let url = 'https://v1.nocodeapi.com/emrescksn/webflow/WAOOrnxdScaWCRlT';
    let res= await fetch(url);
    //let res= await fetch('../json/states.json');
    let states= await res.json();


    let matches=states.filter(state => {
        const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`,`gi`);
        return state.name.match(regex) || state.abbr.match(regex);
    });

    if(searchText.length === 0){
        matches=[];
        matchList.innerHTML='';
    }

    outputHtml(matches);    
};

const outputHtml = matches => {
    if(matches.length > 0) {
        const html=matches.map(match => `
            <div class="card card-body mb-1">
            <h4>${match.name} (${match.abbr}) <a href="https://${match.web}/">Visit W3Schools.com!</a></h4>
            </div>

        `).join('');

        matchList.innerHTML = html;
    }


}


search.addEventListener('input', () => searchStates(search.value));
```

Comment: What do you see when doing `console.log(states);`?

Comment: {items: Array(50), count: 50, limit: 100, offset: 0, total: 50}
count: 50
items: (50) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
limit: 100
offset: 0
total: 50
__proto__: Object  Something like this, content of the .json file in the url.

Comment: So have you tried `states.items.filter` instead? See [How to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The expected JSON result from your question is not the same as the JSON from the API!**

You can use `states.items.filter` instead of `states.filter` but the API linked has no property `abbr` so it will return *undefined*:

```js
const search = document.getElementById('search');
const matchList = document.getElementById('match-list');

const searchStates = async searchText => {


  let url = 'https://v1.nocodeapi.com/emrescksn/webflow/WAOOrnxdScaWCRlT';
  let res = await fetch(url);
  //let res= await fetch('../json/states.json');
  let states = await res.json();

  let matches = states.items.filter(state => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, `gi`);
    return state.name.match(regex);
  });

  if (searchText.length === 0) {
    matches = [];
    matchList.innerHTML = '';
  }

  outputHtml(matches);
};

const outputHtml = matches => {
  if (matches.length > 0) {
    const html = matches.map(match => `
            <div class="card card-body mb-1">
            <h4>${match.name} (${match.abbr}) <a href="https://${match.web}/">Visit W3Schools.com!</a></h4>
            </div>

        `).join('');

    matchList.innerHTML = html;
  }


}


search.addEventListener('input', () => searchStates(search.value));
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search">
<div id="match-list"></div>
```